# Is there a way to grab all the links on a page except ones containing a specific word in selenium?

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying for hours to find a way to do this, and so far I've found nothing. I've tried using find element by css, xpath, and partial text using the not function. I'm trying to scan a webpage for all the links that don't contain the word 'google', and append them to an array.

Keep in mind speak and get_audio are seperate functions I have not included.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='mypath')
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="
driver.get(url + text.lower())
speak("How many articles should I pull?")
n = get_audio()
speak(f"I'll grab {n} articles")
url_array = []
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[not(contains(text(), 'google'))]"):
    url_array.append(a.get_attribute('href'))
print(url_array)
```

I always get something along the lines of find_elements_* can't take (whatever I put in here), or it works but it adds everything to the array, even the ones with google in them. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `//a[not(contains(@href, 'google'))]` xpath?

Comment: I just did, it still returned all the links, not just the ones without google in them.

Comment: So,  ideally your output would be empty as each of the link on that page have `google` in it. Try with `//a[not(contains(@href, 'google'))][not(starts-with(@href,'/'))][not(starts-with(@href,'#'))]` and the result will be `[]`

Comment: There are a series of links that do not contain google, that's what I'm trying to sort into the list.

Comment: Can you please share 1 of such links which you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it by defining a new function and filtering the list after it was made, instead of trying to get selenium to do it.

```
def Filter(string, substr): 
    return [str for str in string if
             any(sub not in str for sub in substr)]
```

Then using that and a filter to get rid of the None

```
url_array_2 = []
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a'):
        url_array_2.append(a.get_attribute('href'))

    url_array_1 = list(filter(None, url_array_2)) 
    flist = ['google']

    url_array = Filter(url_array_1, flist)

    print(url_array)
```

Worked perfectly :)